# Why Byte.parseByte("10000001",2) throws a NFE?

Tags: java, byte, numberformatexception

I have a bitmask to be stored in one byte, as I only need 8 bits. When I'm creating it I do it as a String (I thought it would be easier in this way) and then I transform it to a byte with `Byte.parseByte(mask,2)`, but I found it does not work for certain values:

```
String bits="10000001";
Byte.parseByte(bits,2);// throws a NFE
```

But if I do:

```
byte b=(byte)0x81; //1000 0001
```

There is no problem.

PS: I found a workaround, `byte b=(byte)Integer.parseInt(bits, 2);`but anyway I want to know why I cannot convert 8 bits into a byte

Comment: Short answer: because `byte` is signed.

Comment: Yes, I know it, the first 1 says that is a negative number. My point is that should not be a problem. How can I store -127 then, if I'm receiving an String?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`10000001` binary is `129` decimal. Ergo, it is bigger than `Byte.MAX_VALUE`.

Your solution

```
byte b=(byte)0x81; //1000 0001
```

will result in `b`having the value `-127`. The same holds true for your workaround.

Comment: So it's just Byte.parseByte function is not capable of store a given byte, it needs to transform it to a number before. I thought it would do something like adding 1s and then shifting them. 0x81 is also 129 but it works